# How to start using composer in your project after installation on Windows 10?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, windows-10, dependency-management

I downloaded the **Composer-Setup.exe** and run to install Composer using the installer within few mouse clicks.

Opened terminal by typing in **cmd**. At the command prompt typed in `Composer` and saw all the information related to **Composer** which means I've installed Composer successfully on my Windows 10 machine.

I'm using **XAMPP** for development. So, `C:\xampp\htdocs\` is my document root directory.

I created a new directory titled **composer_demo** in document root. The path of which is `C:\xampp\htdocs\composer_demo`

Now, I want to use composer in this directory. How should I use it?

I went through the documentation but it's not saying anything clearly whether I've to create the **composer.json** file manually inside the directory **composer_demo** or what?

Do I need to write the dependency package manually into **composer.json** file manually or what like?

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

I'm clueless. Please someone give me step-by-step instructions to use the composer inside my newly created directory composer_demo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is just like you said, create a composer.json file on your composer_demo folder, be sure that it is not a text file with a hidden .txt ending. Open the shell inside the folder using shift + right click and selecting ‘Open Command window here’ and run

```
composer install
```

This command tells Composer to install your dependencies, not Composer itself. It will search for a composer.json file and download every dependency you listed there into a vendor folder. Composer will generate a composer.lock file with the versions it downloaded so you don't have problems once the third party libraries update.

Comment: I went to the folder composer_demo using File Explorer. I created a new file composer.json by right-mouse click -> new doc file -
> rename it to composer.json, didn't write anything in it. Now tell me how should I open shell(i.e. command prompt I guess) in the folder composer_json? and why I need to run the comand composer install as I've already installed it on my machine? How can be the monolog package will get install as I have not mentioned it anywhere else? Please give in-detail answer in step-by-step manner. I am not much familiar with shell(i.e. command prompt I guess)

Comment: I was answering as a comment, but as it got too big I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

run .exe file
give php path to `C:\xampp\php`
and
give istallation path to `C:\xampp\htdocs\composer_demo`.

Run shell or cmd

go to your directory. with typing `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\composer_demo\`

now type your keyword ex:- for install php-ffmpeg `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`